# react-beautiful-dnd: overflow breaking Droppable

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using `react-beautiful-dnd` to create draggable divs inside a container.

It works really well as you can see in the GIF below, however because it is inside a scrollable container (`.draggableContainer`), after scrolling down, the drag starts from an incorrect position.

Let me know if anyone would like me to attach some of the CSS.

**This issue is caused by `overflow-y: auto` for `draggableContainer`.**

```
// .draggableContainer has overflow-y: auto
<div className={`${styles.draggableContainer}`}>
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="menuItems">
            {(provided) => (
                <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef} className={styles.menu_container}>
                    {menuItemArr.map((MI, index) => (
                        <Draggable key={MI.id} draggableId={MI.id.toString()} index={MI.id} id={MI.id}>
                            {(provided) => (
                                <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} className={`${styles.popup_form_custom} ${styles.draggable}`}>

                                    <div className={styles.popup_formbox}>
                                        <label className={styles.smaller_font}>Percentage</label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="%" value={MI.percentage} onChange={(selected) => handleMenuArr("percentage", selected.target.value, MI.id)}/>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Draggable>
                    ))}
                    {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
            )}
        </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
</div>
```

Here is an example:

[image]